# Тормозит анимация gif смайлов в TextView

Tags: android, gif, glide

Приложение: аналог форума. В списке отображаются посты участников (html), текст с изображениями, в том числе и gif.

В обычном адаптере для recyclerview, через HtmlCompat.fromHtml загружаю html с тегами img, в которых посредством Glide загружаю gif смайлы из локальных ресурсов.
Проблема в том, что при отображении текста со смайлами в TextView gif анимация сильно тормозит.
Что-бы обойти эту проблему, указываю tv_text.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
Либо через xml разметку android:layerType="software".
Анимация становится нормальной, однако появляется новая проблема: если в TextView очень много текста - он перестает отображаться.

Есть вариант: указать минимальный и максимальный размер шрифта в TextView, но длинные посты из-за этого превращаются в нечитаемый текст (размер шрифта автоматически уменьшается до минимума).
Отключение аппаратного ускорения решает проблему анимации gif, но от этого страдает общая плавность работы приложения.

Нашел пост [TextView with long text invisible with LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE or LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926291/textview-with-long-text-invisible-with-layer-type-hardware-or-layer-type-softwar):  вычисление ширины текста и сравнение с макс. шириной текстуры OpenGL. Этот пример так же не работает.

Пока нахожусь в поиске решений: обрезать текст, с добавление кнопки "раскрыть...", или найти другую реализацию GifDrawable.

```
public class GlideImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter, Drawable.Callback {
    private final Resources resources;
    private final TextView textView;
    HashMap<String, String> icons;
    int width=-1;

    public GlideImageGetter(Resources resources, TextView tv_text, int width) {
        this.resources = resources;
        this.textView = tv_text;
        this.width = width;
        new GlideImageGetter(resources, tv_text);
    }

    public GlideImageGetter(Resources resources, TextView target) {
        super();
        this.resources = resources;
        this.textView = target;
        this.icons = Utils.getIcons();
    }

    CustomTarget<Drawable> customTarget(final FutureDrawable result){
        return new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {

                int maxWidth = 300;
                if (resource instanceof GifDrawable) {
                    GifDrawable gifDrawable = (GifDrawable) resource;

                    if (gifDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() > maxWidth) {
                        float aspectRatio = (float) gifDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) gifDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                        gifDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, maxWidth, (int) (aspectRatio * maxWidth));
                    } else {
                        int width=(int) (gifDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 2.5) ;
                        int height=(int) (gifDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 2.5);
                        gifDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
                    }

                    result.isGif=true;
                    result.setDrawable(gifDrawable);

                    //смайлы-гифки запускаем автоматически
                    if (result.isLocalImage) {
                        gifDrawable.setCallback(GlideImageGetter.this);
                        gifDrawable.start();
                    }

                } else {
                    if (resource.getIntrinsicWidth() > maxWidth) {
                        float aspectRatio = (float) resource.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) resource.getIntrinsicWidth();
                        resource.setBounds(0, 0, maxWidth, (int) (aspectRatio * maxWidth));
                    } else {
                        resource.setBounds(0, 0, resource.getIntrinsicWidth(), resource.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    }
                    result.setDrawable(resource);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                if (null != placeholder) {
                    if (placeholder instanceof GifDrawable)
                        ((GifDrawable) placeholder).stop();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        if (source==null) return null;

        final FutureDrawable result = new FutureDrawable(resources);

        //загружаем "пустую картинку"
        Drawable empty = ContextCompat.getDrawable(textView.getContext(), R.drawable.ic_empty_image);
        if (this.width>0){
            empty = new ScaleDrawable(empty, 0, width, width).getDrawable();
            empty.setBounds(0, 0, this.width, this.width);
            result.setBounds(0, 0, this.width, this.width);
        } else
            result.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());
        result.setDrawable(empty);

        final String imgsource;
        //поменялся путь к локальным смайлам форума
        if (source.contains("local=")) {
            String src=icons.get(source.replace("local=",""));
            imgsource = source.replace(source, "file:///android_asset/icons/"+src);
            result.isLocalImage=true;
        } else
            imgsource=source;

        if (!result.isLocalImage)
            if (VideoUtils.isVideoFast(source))
                result.isVideo=true;

        if (result.isLocalImage){
            GlideApp.with(textView)
                    .load(Uri.parse(imgsource))
                    .into(customTarget(result));
        } else
            GlideApp.with(textView)
                .asDrawable()
                .placeholder(empty)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_error_image)
                .load(Uri.parse(imgsource))
                .centerInside() //облегчаем
                .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565) //облегчаем
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                .into(customTarget(result));

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(@NonNull Drawable drawable) {\
        //textView.invalidate();
        textView.invalidate(drawable.getBounds());
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduleDrawable(@NonNull Drawable drawable, @NonNull Runnable runnable, long l) {
    }

    @Override
    public void unscheduleDrawable(@NonNull Drawable drawable, @NonNull Runnable runnable) {
    }

    public class FutureDrawable extends Drawable  {
        private Drawable drawable;
        public boolean isGif=false;
        public boolean isVideo=false;
        public boolean isLocalImage=false;
        Bitmap play;

        private Bitmap getBitmap(Drawable vectorDrawable) {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        }

        @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
        FutureDrawable(Resources res) {
            play = getBitmap(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
            if(drawable != null) {
                drawable.draw(canvas);
                if (!isLocalImage && (isGif || isVideo)) {
                    //рисуем значок play поверх изображения

                    //если гифка запущена - не рисуем
                    if (this.drawable instanceof GifDrawable && ((GifDrawable) this.drawable).isRunning())
                        return;

                    //т.к. размер картинки может быть не пропорциональным
                    //берем размер например высоты
                    int width = getBounds().width() / 4;
                    int height = width;

                    if (width == 0 | height == 0) {
                        width = play.getWidth();
                        height = play.getHeight();
                    }

                    play = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(play, width, height, false);

                    int x = (getBounds().width() - width) / 2;
                    int y = (getBounds().height() - height) / 2;
                    canvas.drawBitmap(play, x, y, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
                }
            }
        }

        public void play() {
            if (drawable != null) {
                if (isGif) {
                    GifDrawable gif=((GifDrawable) this.drawable);
                    if (gif.isRunning()) {
                        gif.stop();
                        gif.invalidateSelf();
                        gif.setCallback(null);
                        this.setDrawable(drawable); //draw() скрин с иконкой play
                    }else {
                        this.setDrawable(gif); //draw()
                        gif.setCallback(GlideImageGetter.this);
                        gif.start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Drawable getCurrent() {
            return drawable;
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int i) {
        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return PixelFormat.UNKNOWN;
        }

        public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable){
            this.drawable=drawable;

            int drawableWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int drawableHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            if (isGif){
                drawableWidth = (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 2.5);
                drawableHeight = (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()* 2.5);
            }

            int maxWidth = textView.getMeasuredWidth();
            if (drawableWidth > maxWidth) {
                int calculatedHeight = maxWidth * drawableHeight / drawableWidth;
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, maxWidth, calculatedHeight);
                setBounds(0, 0, maxWidth, calculatedHeight);
            } else {
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawableWidth, drawableHeight);
                setBounds(0, 0, drawableWidth, drawableHeight);
            }

            //для изменения размера картинок
            //textView.setText(textView.getText());
            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(textView.getText());
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

В адаптере:

```
public class PostAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<PostView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        switch(getItemViewType(position)){
            case ITEM:
                final PostView post = getItem(position);
                final PostHolder postHolder=((PostHolder)holder);

                SpannableStringBuilder text=(SpannableStringBuilder)HtmlCompat.fromHtml(post.text, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, new GlideImageGetter(resources,postHolder.tv_text), new Html.TagHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable editable, XMLReader xmlReader) {
                    }
                });

                postHolder.tv_text.setText(text);
```

В разметке:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="tv_text"
    />
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос разметку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Дополнено 2.**

На официальном страничке https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2471 предлагают откатиться на версию Glide 3.7.0, и установить у ImageView точные размеры android:layout_width, android:layout_height. Однако меня больше интересует анимация в HTML.

Нашел еще один вариант с плавной gif анимацией: выкидываем Glide, используем AnimationDrawable.

1. Создаем AnimationDrawable
2. Загружаем .gif файл, вытаскиваем каждый кадр с помощью GifDecoder (в интернете полно реализаций), и собственно добавляем эти кадры `addFrame(drawable, decoder.getDelay(i));`

Способы применения:

1. Для ImageView просто присваиваем и анимация работает автоматически: `imageView.setImageDrawable(gif);`
2. Для TextView необходимо:

- создать новый класс AnimatedImageSpan расширяющий DynamicDrawableSpan
- реализовать в новом классе пиналку (на основе Handler), которая заставит перерисовывать TextView
- сформировать Spanned разметку, вставить туда наш новый класс AnimatedImageSpan
- установить в качестве коллбэка TextView: `gif3.setCallback(textview);`

3. Для преобразования HTML в текст с gif анимацией необходимо:

- берем наш новый класс AnimatedImageSpan, и расширяем интерфейсами Runnable, Animatable, получаем MyGifDrawable
- расширяем Html.ImageGetter, для gif изображений используем новый MyGifDrawable

Альтернативный второй вариант - расширить класс TextView (назовем его HTMLTextView), который при присвоении текста вытащит все AnimatedImageSpan, и самостоятельно установит коллбэк `drawable.setCallback(HTMLTextView.this);`. Что удобно - можно ставить анимацию на паузу и запускать когда угодно.

Анимация не тормозит в ImageView, TextView, RecyclerView.

Тестовый проект с превью: https://github.com/virex-84/GifTest

Answer (score 0):

**Дополнено.**

Сразу после присвоения теста (postHolder.tv_text.setText(text)), попробовал рыть в сторону [TextView with long text invisible with LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE or LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926291/textview-with-long-text-invisible-with-layer-type-hardware-or-layer-type-softwar). Однако, хоть на эмуляторе такая конструкция работает, но на реальном устройстве нет:

```
int width = (int) tv_text.getPaint().measureText(tv_text.getText().toString());

int[] maxGlTexSize = new int[1];
GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxGlTexSize, 0);
if (width < maxGlTexSize[0]) {
  //Log.e("Debug", "Too big for GL");
  tv_text.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
} else {
  //Log.i("Debug", "Small enough for GL");
  tv_text.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}
```

Проблема (насколько я понял) в том, что мы не знаем, какая версия opengl используется для аппаратного ускорения.
Можно получить максимальный размер текстуры и таким способом:

```
public static int getSupportedMaxPictureSize() {
    int[] array = new int[1];
    GLES10.glGetIntegerv(GLES10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, array, 0);

    try {
        if (array[0] == 0) {
            GLES11.glGetIntegerv(GLES11.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, array, 0);

            if (array[0] == 0) {
                GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, array, 0);

                if (array[0] == 0) {
                    GLES30.glGetIntegerv(GLES30.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, array, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        // Ignore the exception
    }

    return array[0] != 0 ? array[0] : 2048;
}
```

Но это тоже не поможет.

В итоге, обратил внимание что в логах появляется текст:

> W/View: MaterialTextView not displayed because it is too large to fit
> into a software layer (or drawing cache), needs 10470408 bytes, only
> 10368000 available

В View buildDrawingCacheImpl как раз происходит вывод такого сообщения.

Поэтому, мы постараемся вычислить максимальный размер кэша каждого поста и отключим аппаратное ускорение, если размер нашего текста не помещается в текст.
Устанавливаем в xml разметке для TextView android:layerType="none".
И в адаптере пишем:

```
public class PostAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<PostView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        switch(getItemViewType(position)){
            case ITEM:
                final PostView post = getItem(position);
                final PostHolder postHolder=((PostHolder)holder);

                SpannableStringBuilder text=(SpannableStringBuilder)HtmlCompat.fromHtml(post.text, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, new GlideImageGetter(resources,postHolder.tv_text), new Html.TagHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable editable, XMLReader xmlReader) {
                    }
                });

                postHolder.tv_text.setText(text);

                postHolder.tv_text.post(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    int width = tv_text.getMeasuredWidth();  //get width
                    int heigth = tv_text.getMeasuredHeight();  //get height
                    boolean opaque = tv_text.isOpaque();
                    boolean use32BitCache = false;

                    long max = ViewConfiguration.get(tv_text.getContext()).getScaledMaximumDrawingCacheSize();
                    long need = width * heigth * (opaque && !use32BitCache ? 2 : 4);

                    if (max > need) {
                      if (tv_text.getLayerType()!=View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE)
                        tv_text.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                    } else {
                      if (tv_text.getLayerType()!=View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE)
                        tv_text.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
                    }
                    }
                  });
```

Таким образом, если размер кэша больше чем нужен для отрисовки большого текста в TextView, мы отключаем аппаратное ускорение, и gif анимация работает плавно. Если текст очень большой - оставляем аппаратное ускорение что-бы он мог быть отрисованным, хотя и теряем в плавности анимации gif.